# lifecycle methods are not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to check if the user is followed by the current user or not. I am running this function in 'componentDidMount'. But I am getting the below error:

UserProfile.js:29 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

According to docs, `componentdidmount` triggers after 1st render. here I should get the value in 1st render through componentWillMount. But it is not happening.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import PostListItem from './PostListItem';
import {getUser, addFollower, addFollowing, removeFollower, removeFollowing} 
from '../actions/user';
class UserProfile extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
        user:'',
        isFollowed: false
    } 
}

componentWillMount(){
    console.log(this.props.match.params._id);
    axios

.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/${this.props.match.params._id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({user: res.data});
            this.props.dispatch(getUser(res.data));
        }); 
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.user.following.includes(this.props.currentUser.uid)){
        this.setState({isFollowed: true});
    }
}


render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <div className="User-description">
                  {this.state.user.avatar}
                  <img src={this.state.user.avatar} alt= 
{this.state.user.name}/>
                </div>
                {(this.props.currentUser.uid === this.state.user._id) ?
                    <Link to={`/${this.state.user._id}/edit`}>Edit 
Profile</Link> :
                    <button 
                    onClick={this.onFollow}>
                    {this.state.isFollowed? 'Following': 'Follow'}
                </button>
                }
            </div>
)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
console.log(state);
 return{ 
     currentUser: state.auth
    // user: state.user.find(user => user._id === props.match.params._id)
 }
};  

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserProfile);
```

Comment: In this code I can only see `componentDidUpdate`, not `componentDidMount`. `componentDidUpdate` is not called after initial render. Also, `componentWillMount` is deprecated and should be avoided. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting

Answer (score 1):

Remember, below is an async computation in your code:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/${this.props.match.params._id}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({user: res.data});
            this.props.dispatch(getUser(res.data));
        });
```

Your promise handler will set the state eventually when rest of the events in the queue are processed. Here `componentDidMount()` or `componentDidUpdate()` executes just after the `render()`. Your `then` handler wasn't executed until then and thus `user.following` isn't set in your state.
Try putting a check if field `following` exists then only proceed because eventually it will be set:

```
componentDidUpdate(){

    if(this.state.user.following && this.state.user.following.includes(this.props.currentUser.uid)){
        this.setState({isFollowed: true});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `user` and `following` before using `includes`:

```
if(this.state.user && 
   this.state.user.following.includes(this.props.currentUser.uid)){
```